# MYSQL: update field with random fixed char

Tags: mysql

would like to update all record on a field which i only want it to fill it with random either **Y** or **N**

currently using:

> update table1 set field1=( RAND() FROM Y FOR N)

which is not working, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

solved with this:

```
update table1 set field1 = case floor(1 + rand()*2) when 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end;
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter alternative is the inline IF:

```
update table1 set field1 = IF(rand()*2 > 1, 'Y', 'N');
```

You can try it out with this demo SELECT:

```
SELECT IF(rand()*2 > 1, 'Y', 'N') AS indecision_demo;
```